# How to resolve the state change inside a for loop?

Tags: javascript, firebase, state, firebase-storage

```
for (var i = 0; i < e.target.files.length; i++) {
    var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref('user_files/' + e.target.files[i].name).put(e.target.files[i]);
    storageRef.on('state_changed', null, null, function (snapshot) {
        var downloadURL = storageRef.snapshot.downloadURL;

        //i need all the files URL
        //but always get the last file URL
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call `put()` is returns an [`UploadTask`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.UploadTask). In addition to the `on()` method you use, that also implements `then()`. This means you can use it as a promise and thus use `Promise.all`:

```
for (var i = 0; i < e.target.files.length; i++) {
    var promises = firebase.storage().ref('user_files/' + e.target.files[i].name).put(e.target.files[i]);
    Promise.all(promises).then(function(results) {
        var downloadURLs = results.map(function(taskSnapshot) {
            return taskSnapshot.downloadURL
        });
    })
}
```

A slightly more modern version of the above code:

```
var files = firebase.storage().ref('user_files');

var promises = e.target.files.map((f) => files.child(f.name).put(f));

Promise.all(promises).then((results) => {
    var downloadURLs = results.map((taskSnapshot) => taskSnapshot.downloadURL);
})
```